# MVC JQuery call from url without action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, routes, action

I have localhost:51775/Book/Index/bookname page and it working without problem. But what I want is to remove Index from url and make it appear as localhost:51775/Book/bookname , I can do the page link as I wanted but this time jquery calls do not work.

I have added a new route to routeconfig as

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Book",
            "Book/{id}",
            new { controller = "Book", action = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Jquery call from this url as http://localhost:51775/Book/bookname doesn't work;

```
 var data = new FormData();
    data.append("comment", comment);
    data.append("id", id);

var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Book/AddBookComment",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data
    });
```

but if I remove routeconfig then it works as http://localhost:51775/Book/Index/bookname

Here is the c# method which is called from jquery;

```
[HttpPost]
    public string AddBookComment()
    {
        string comment = Request.Form["comment"];
        string id = Request.Form["id"];

        Int64 idBook = id.ToInt64();
        SuggestBusiness.Instance.AddBookComment(idBook, SessionManager.GetSession().CurrentMember.MemberId, comment);
        return "ok";
    }
```

localhost:51775/Book/Index/bookname is the working page link, localhost:51775/Book/bookname is the page link that I want it to work, localhost:51775/Book/AddBookComment is the c# method for jquery

What should I do to make that jquery call?

Comment: It that route the first one in your `RouteConfig` file (i.e. before the default route)?

Comment: yes it is the first one.

Comment: Can id parameter be only numbers?

Comment: Then show the method your `Index()` method that your posting to.

Comment: Actually I don't use parameter we can ignore it since I send parameters from form data.

Comment: And the jquery method you have shown is a POST, not a GET, so its unclear what you actually asking

Comment: I have added c# method, I don't see what is unclear, I want to send comment from jquery. It works on default route config but it doesn't work when I remove the action from the routeconfig.

Comment: Since `url: "/Book/AddBookComment",` matches your `Book` route you will  need to add another route `"BookComment", "Book/AddBookComment", new { controller = "Book", action = "AddBookComment" }`

Comment: Yes, it works now, Thanks @StephenMuecke , Can you add your answer please

Comment: @StephenMuecke please add your answer, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a route with `url: "Book/{id}"` it means that in you ajax call, `url: "/Book/AddBookComment",` will match that route and send you to the `Index()` method. Either remove the route or you can add another specific route (needs to be before your `"Book"` route)

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "BookComment",
   "Book/AddBookComment",
   new { controller = "Book", action = "AddBookComment" }
);
.... // your other routes
```

Comment: I kept the both route for book page and comment action, and it works, thx stephen

Answer (score 0):

the url changes according to area, view folder etc.. The better thing is use url action to create the url, set that value to a variable and use that variable value in ajax call instead of hard coding. See the example below

```
var url ='@Url.Action("YourMethod", "ControllerName")';

var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data
    });
```

`@Url.Action`   will not work in external scripts so if you are using external script, you have to set the url in view.

Answer (score 0):

problem is your default route action is `index` so you cannot call  `AddBookComment` methord . try to change your default route action to this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
    routes.MapRoute(
                "Book",
                "Book/{id}",
                new { controller = "Book", action = "AddBookComment", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Jquery

```
 var url = '@Url.Action("AddBookComment","Book")'
                    var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: data
                    });
```

Comment: If I change the default route as you showed then the project didn't work.

Comment: no i mean keep your default route as it is add this route optionally to your route table. i edited my answer

Comment: This time localhost:51775/Book/bookname link doesn't work!

Comment: localhost:51775/Book/Index/bookname  is the working page link, localhost:51775/Book/bookname is the page link that I want it to work, localhost:51775/Book/AddBookComment is the c# method for jquery

Comment: ok sorry i made mistake add default route to end of the route collection. (simple put bottom book router to top)

Comment: I have already did it that way. But localhost:51775/Book/bookname link doesn't work.

Comment: No it didn't work!  localhost:51775/Book/bookname link doesn't work

Comment: what is that bookname?

Comment: if I set the routeconfig as I showed in the question then the page link is became as I wanted like 'localhost:51775/Book/bookname' but for your solution page link is same as localhost:51775/Book/Index/bookname so when I remove index it gives that error.

Comment: bookname is something like 'insan-isterse-azmin-zaferi-oykuleri-5'

Comment: I just don't want index in the page url, that is what i want.

Comment: `localhost:51775/Book/bookname` will hit the first routing `localhost:51775/Book/Index/bookname` will hit default routing

Comment: I have made a samll sample for my case, and uploaded here http://www.filedropper.com/mvcapplication5 you can check the situation from here. Click show book and then try to add comment. it works now the  book link is not as  i wanted so when you remove index it doesn't work.

Comment: the solution was adding routeconfigs for both book page and addcomment  action.

Answer (score 0):

try using following code to register your route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Book",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Book", action = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

"{controller}/{action}/{id}" is used to define a template which makes MVC understand the route, then you give it a default instance.

Comment: @kubilay I think you should try Gayan Ranasinghe's answer then. You need both default route and a customized route for your requirement.

Comment: I already have both, routeconfig as I wrote in the question is working for the page link. But jquery call doesn't work!