# ASP.NET MVC - JQuery call from url without action not working

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a http://localhost:54393/CreateTest/4fwp36 which working fine but when I call http://localhost:54393/CreateTest/RemoveControlsNew from jQuery ajax then it is not working giving an error also not calling into a controller if any one can help me out as I am stuck here more then 1 day

I have tried this but it's not working:

[MVC JQuery call from url without action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33206672/mvc-jquery-call-from-url-without-action)

This is my route config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "CreateTest",
           url: "CreateTest/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "CreateTest", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

Above code works perfectly when I call from another controller calling it like this:

```
return Redirect("/CreateTest/"+ strTestID);
```

When I try to call on same controller with ajax post method

```
RemoveControls: function (rid) {
    var MyAppUrlSettings = {
        MyUsefulUrl: "/CreateTest/RemoveControlsNew"
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false,
        //url: '@Url.Action("RemoveControlsNew",Request.Url.Scheme)',
        url: MyAppUrlSettings.MyUsefulUrl,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: {
            rid: rid,
            bgcolor: CREATETEST.globalbgcolor,
            fontcolor: CREATETEST.globalfontcolor,
            fontsize: CREATETEST.globalfontsize
        },
        success:
            function (response) {
                var data = response;
                if (data == 'Error') {
                    CREATETEST.showerror('Some thing went wrong you cannot remove a question at the moment for selected option');
                }
                else {
                    $("#AddControlNew").load(location.href + " #AddControlNew");                       
                }
            },
        error:                
            function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                CREATETEST.showerror("Error: " + response);
            }
    });
},
```

Then these is not working and my method is not called.

I am getting this error:

[Error on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPAEj.png)

[Controller code for Ajax call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxbBG.png)
[Regular Controller code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k1Gj.png)

Comment: Please post, your ajax and controller code

Comment: Below is my route config
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "CreateTest",
               url: "CreateTest/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "CreateTest", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
Which works fine when i called it from another controller but when i call it from external js for ajax call on same controller with different action then it doesn't work my js is below
url : "/CreateTest/RemoveControlsNew"

Comment: Can you please add the Controller action (Index) please

Comment: Added please check with above URL's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "Error on Page" image doesn't show anything useful, are you getting a `404`, `202`,  `405` Header Status Code

Please post code, not images.

Apply the `[FromBody]` attribute to a parameter to populate its properties from the body of an HTTP request. The ASP.NET Core runtime delegates the responsibility of reading the body to an input formatter.

```
public JsonResult RemoveControlsNew([FromBody] int rid, string bgcolor, string fontcolor, string fontsize)
```